# MongoDB date range search without timestamp

Tags: mongodb

I have the following record in my mongodb collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7641b0d4b6828ad37c9a66"),
    "factor" : 1,
    "postdate" : ISODate("2018-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
}
```

I want to do a search where I do not factor the timestamp, only the year, month, day.  How can I do that?

The following does not work because the record has a time stamp that makes it not show up in my search:

```
db.transtest.find({postdate: { $gte : new Date("2018-01-01"), $lte : new Date("2018-01-31")}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include all of the last day of the month, use `$lt` and the first day of the next month:

```
db.transtest.find({postdate: { $gte: new Date("2018-01-01"), $lt: new Date("2018-02-01")}})
```

Comment: I'm aware I can do that, but I don't want to.  I will do it as a last resort.

Comment: I did find out that this has something to do with the way dates are stored in MongoDB using the local timezone offset. So if you store a date using only year, month day, an offset will be added to reflect your timezone.  Then when you are doing a search on date ranges you get a value that may be off by a day.  Is there a mongodb query solution that allows the time to be stripped totally from the date?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add max day time to your $lt date criteria :

```
db.transtest.find({postdate: { $gte : new Date("2018-01-01"), $lte : new Date("2018-01-31T23:59:59.999Z")}})
```

You're sure to get all results because the precision of an ISOdate is millisecond

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

Moreover, it automatically take care of timezone, since the record

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b459ef6744c541aa898cdd4"), 
    "factor" : 1, 
    "postdate" : ISODate("2018-02-01T00:10:00.000+0100")  // <== Note the date with +1 hour TZ, same as  ISODate("2018-01-31T23:10:00.000Z")
}
```

will be returned too.